# Why the if condition evaluate is failing, if we have multiple conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements

While I am executing the below code, the condition is getting passed without breaking the execution.

While in the second loop, this condition check should fail `[int(a[i])==0]`. But I am seeing that it is getting passed . Can I please know the answer.

I tried with the below code, this condition is getting failed. But if i include the multiple condition it is failing.

`a=['0']
if int(a[0])==0 :
    print ("invalid")`

Actual Code

```
a="25605511135"
str=''
for i in range(0,len(a),3) :
 word = a[i:i+3]
 print(a[i])
 lis= [int(a[i])==0,int(word) > 255]
 if all(lis):
  print("Invalid")
  break
```

Expected Results should be : - 2 0 Invalid

And break statement should get executed

Comment: What do you think that `[int(a[i])==0,int(word) > 255]` is doing? *hint* `0,int(word) > 255` is evaluated as tuple `(0, int(word) > 255)`

Comment: How exactly you want to produce `invalid`, if at `i = 6` `word` will be equal to `111`, which is less, than `255`?

Comment: Please, for the love of whatever you hold dear, _don't use single space indentation_ (especially in Python). It is very hard to read, and in languages where indentation is significant it requires a surprising amount of additional focus to read. Thoughtful use of blank lines can also aid readability. Python is designed to be readable. Its [official style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends _four-space indentation_.

Comment: `str` is a builtin funtion. please do not use it as variable. you are overwriting `lis` in each iteration. I suppose you meant `lis.append(int(a[i])==0 or int(word) > 255)`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The values of `word` are 256, 055, 111, 35. (print them out too, to see).
- The values of `a[i]` are 2, 0, 1, 3.

`all(lis)` would only be true if `a[i]` is 0 and `word` > 255, which never happens with your input string. So your code appears to be doing as it is written to do.

You need to clarify what your criteria are, and how you wish to evaluate them.